# FileInputStream / ObjectInputStream: StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format

Tags: java, android, serialization

When reading a serialized object from a file, I get:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0

The object, which implements Serializable is saved and restored as such:

Save:

```
    try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = getContext().openFileOutput("gameState.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(gameAssets);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Restore:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = getContext().openFileInput("gameState.ser");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        gameAssets = (GameAssets) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted the surrounding code, I am not sure if this is the case, or the source of the error.

But you should always close your streams after writing to them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the fields on gameAssets are serializeable. If one of them is not an exception can be printed into the file you created which can cause an exception on read of that file.